# Java - not able to load json string to object, every element is null

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to load this test json string into an object using Gson but every element carries null. There is no exception triggered during the conversion. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.
Appreciate your help.

I am writing a longer comment here only because it is throwing an error for not writing enough text to ask my query. I can't imagine why it would do such checks.

```
String testSeg1 = "{\"FlightSegment\":{\"discount\":0,\"childTaxBreakup\":\"0,0,0\",\"adultTaxBreakup\":\"0,154,413\",\"viaFlight\":\"\",\"airportTaxInfant\":0,\"OperatingAirlineFlightNumber\":144,\"StopQuantity\":0,\"BookingClass\":{\"Availability\":9,\"ResBookDesigCode\":\"S\"},\"AirEquipType\":\"77W\",\"RPH\":\"\",\"airportTax\":567,\"airportTaxChild\":0,\"OperatingAirlineCode\":\"AI\",\"DepartureDateTime\":\"2017-11-27T17:00:00\",\"ArrivalDateTime\":\"2017-11-27T19:10:00\",\"imageFileName\":\"http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif\",\"FlightNumber\":144,\"airLineName\":\"Air India\",\"DepartureAirportCode\":\"BOM\",\"octax\":0,\"ArrivalAirportCode\":\"DEL\",\"BookingClassFare\":{\"bookingclass\":\"S\",\"adultFare\":3955,\"commissionOnTCharge\":0,\"farebasiscode\":\"glW5J3cLgtM=\",\"Rule\":\"This fare is Non Refundable <br> Baggage : 25K<br>Booking Class : S|Re-Schedule Charges: Rs. 750 per sector + Fare difference (If any) +admin fee 500 + Service Fee of Rs. 250 Sector .|Cancellation Charges : Basic fare +Airline administration fee 500  + Service Charges 250 Per Passenger Per Sector .\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t    |\",\"adultCommission\":0,\"childCommission\":0,\"classType\":\"Economy\"},\"infantTaxBreakup\":\"0,0,0\"}}";
                Type testlistType = new TypeToken<FlightSegment>(){}.getType();
                FlightSegment testFlt = gson.fromJson(testSeg1, testlistType);

public class FlightSegment {

@SerializedName("Discount")
@Expose
private String discount;

@SerializedName("AirEquipType")
@Expose
private String airEquipType;
@SerializedName("ArrivalAirportCode")
@Expose
private String arrivalAirportCode;
@SerializedName("ArrivalDateTime")
@Expose
private String arrivalDateTime;
@SerializedName("DepartureAirportCode")
@Expose
private String departureAirportCode;
@SerializedName("DepartureDateTime")
@Expose
private String departureDateTime;
@SerializedName("FlightNumber")
@Expose
private String flightNumber;
@SerializedName("OperatingAirlineCode")
@Expose
private String operatingAirlineCode;
@SerializedName("OperatingAirlineFlightNumber")
@Expose
private String operatingAirlineFlightNumber;
@SerializedName("RPH")
@Expose
private String rPH;
@SerializedName("StopQuantity")
@Expose
private String stopQuantity;
@SerializedName("airLineName")
@Expose
private String airLineName;
@SerializedName("airportTax")
@Expose
private String airportTax;
@SerializedName("imageFileName")
@Expose
private String imageFileName;
@SerializedName("viaFlight")
@Expose
private String viaFlight;

@SerializedName("airportTaxChild")
@Expose
private String airportTaxChild;
@SerializedName("airportTaxInfant")
@Expose
private String airportTaxInfant;
@SerializedName("adultTaxBreakup")
@Expose
private String adultTaxBreakup;
@SerializedName("childTaxBreakup")
@Expose
private String childTaxBreakup;
@SerializedName("infantTaxBreakup")
@Expose
private String infantTaxBreakup;
@SerializedName("octax")
@Expose
private String octax;

@SerializedName("BookingClass")
@Expose
private BookingClass bookingClass;
@SerializedName("BookingClassFare")
@Expose
private BookingClassFare bookingClassFare;

public String getAirEquipType() {
return airEquipType;
}

public void setAirEquipType(String airEquipType) {
this.airEquipType = airEquipType;
}

public String getArrivalAirportCode() {
return arrivalAirportCode;
}

public void setArrivalAirportCode(String arrivalAirportCode) {
this.arrivalAirportCode = arrivalAirportCode;
}

public String getArrivalDateTime() {
return arrivalDateTime;
}

public void setArrivalDateTime(String arrivalDateTime) {
this.arrivalDateTime = arrivalDateTime;
}

public String getDepartureAirportCode() {
return departureAirportCode;
}

public void setDepartureAirportCode(String departureAirportCode) {
this.departureAirportCode = departureAirportCode;
}

public String getDepartureDateTime() {
return departureDateTime;
}

public void setDepartureDateTime(String departureDateTime) {
this.departureDateTime = departureDateTime;
}

public String getFlightNumber() {
return flightNumber;
}

public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
}

public String getOperatingAirlineCode() {
return operatingAirlineCode;
}

public void setOperatingAirlineCode(String operatingAirlineCode) {
this.operatingAirlineCode = operatingAirlineCode;
}

public String getOperatingAirlineFlightNumber() {
return operatingAirlineFlightNumber;
}

public void setOperatingAirlineFlightNumber(String operatingAirlineFlightNumber) {
this.operatingAirlineFlightNumber = operatingAirlineFlightNumber;
}

public String getRPH() {
return rPH;
}

public void setRPH(String rPH) {
this.rPH = rPH;
}

public String getStopQuantity() {
return stopQuantity;
}

public void setStopQuantity(String stopQuantity) {
this.stopQuantity = stopQuantity;
}

public String getAirLineName() {
return airLineName;
}

public void setAirLineName(String airLineName) {
this.airLineName = airLineName;
}

public String getAirportTax() {
return airportTax;
}

public void setAirportTax(String airportTax) {
this.airportTax = airportTax;
}

public String getImageFileName() {
return imageFileName;
}

public void setImageFileName(String imageFileName) {
this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
}

public String getViaFlight() {
return viaFlight;
}

public void setViaFlight(String viaFlight) {
this.viaFlight = viaFlight;
}

public BookingClass getBookingClass() {
return bookingClass;
}

public void setBookingClass(BookingClass bookingClass) {
this.bookingClass = bookingClass;
}

public BookingClassFare getBookingClassFare() {
return bookingClassFare;
}

public void setBookingClassFare(BookingClassFare bookingClassFare) {
this.bookingClassFare = bookingClassFare;
}

public String getDiscount() {
return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount) {
this.discount = discount;
}

public String getAirportTaxChild() {
return airportTaxChild;
}

public void setAirportTaxChild(String airportTaxChild) {
this.airportTaxChild = airportTaxChild;
}

public String getAirportTaxInfant() {
return airportTaxInfant;
}

public void setAirportTaxInfant(String airportTaxInfant) {
this.airportTaxInfant = airportTaxInfant;
}

public String getAdultTaxBreakup() {
return adultTaxBreakup;
}

public void setAdultTaxBreakup(String adultTaxBreakup) {
this.adultTaxBreakup = adultTaxBreakup;
}

public String getChildTaxBreakup() {
return childTaxBreakup;
}

public void setChildTaxBreakup(String childTaxBreakup) {
this.childTaxBreakup = childTaxBreakup;
}

public String getInfantTaxBreakup() {
return infantTaxBreakup;
}

public void setInfantTaxBreakup(String infantTaxBreakup) {
this.infantTaxBreakup = infantTaxBreakup;
}

public String getOctax() {
return octax;
}

public void setOctax(String octax) {
this.octax = octax;
}

}
```

This is the JSON String -

```
{"FlightSegment":{"discount":0,"childTaxBreakup":"0,0,0","adultTaxBreakup":"0,154,413","viaFlight":"","airportTaxInfant":0,"OperatingAirlineFlightNumber":144,"StopQuantity":0,"BookingClass":{"Availability":9,"ResBookDesigCode":"S"},"AirEquipType":"77W","RPH":"","airportTax":567,"airportTaxChild":0,"OperatingAirlineCode":"AI","DepartureDateTime":"2017-11-27T17:00:00","ArrivalDateTime":"2017-11-27T19:10:00","imageFileName":"http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif","FlightNumber":144,"airLineName":"Air India","DepartureAirportCode":"BOM","octax":0,"ArrivalAirportCode":"DEL","BookingClassFare":{"bookingclass":"S","adultFare":3955,"commissionOnTCharge":0,"farebasiscode":"glW5J3cLgtM=","Rule":"This fare is Non Refundable <br> Baggage : 25K<br>Booking Class : S|Re-Schedule Charges: Rs. 750 per sector + Fare difference (If any) +admin fee 500 + Service Fee of Rs. 250 Sector .|Cancellation Charges : Basic fare +Airline administration fee 500  + Service Charges 250 Per Passenger Per Sector .ttttt    |","adultCommission":0,"childCommission":0,"classType":"Economy"},"infantTaxBreakup":"0,0,0"}}
```

Comment: It actually hurts my eyes to look at the json you have copied!

Comment: Please fix your indentation and make a [mcve].

Comment: Apologies for the long code but I pasted the entire thing here as a minimal version is working but the complete one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TypeToken because your are not loading a List of Objects, use the class directly :

```
FlightSegment testFlt = gson.fromJson(testSeg1, FlightSegment.class);
```

Comment: Tried this but still no luck, every element is null

Comment: Expected object found "Document :"...... It shows a part of the json string. I tried analysing the json string online, it is a valid one. If I take a part of the json string, hard code it and then try to load the object, it works fine. But when I take the entire string as received from the server, though it is a valid one, it shows this error.

Comment: Could you put the jsontring from the server in your questio?

Comment: What I have pasted there is the string I received from server

Comment: Then print this string: testSeg1 , en copy the result in youe question , because now your json is not readable

Comment: Done, added now

Comment: looks like fine, could you copy and paste the error log, also update your code with my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159851/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-diegoveloper).